# VBA Range and String confusion

Tags: string, excel, vba, range

Think I'm having a problem with the difference between ranges and strings. Trying to get it to search the cells in the range for any of the winners then spit out a point value.

```
Sub it()
Dim Round1 As Range
Dim Round2 As Range
Dim lngCnt As Long
Dim Winner() As String
Dim pointSum As Double
ReDim Winner(1 To 4)
    Winner(1) = "Mohler"
    Winner(2) = "Scotter"
    Winner(3) = "DKGAY"
    Winner(4) = "Lassie"
Set Round1 = Range("L3,L11,L22,L32").Text
For Each Winner In Round1
lngCnt = lngCnt + 10
Winner(lngCnt) = pointSum.Value
Next
MsgBox pointSum.Value    
End Sub
```

Comment: First step: `Set Round1 = Range("L3,L11,L22,L32").Text` remove the `.text` and I think you need a `union`.

Comment: What's `Winner(lngCnt) = pointSum.Value` doing? You don't have a `Winner(11)` value, which is the first thing it'll look for, no? (or 10)

Comment: Yes you are using `Winner` as a range and a string array.  It is not exactly clear what you are trying to do.  The array only goes to 4 yet you are trying to refer to every 10th one with your `lngcnt`.  Also pointSum is never assigned a value and therefor it will always = 0.  So maybe tell us what you are trying to do.

Comment: Thanks all for the comments, sorry, very new to VBA and programming in general student who's trying to simplify work. @ScottCraner I'm trying to add +10 to pointSum everytime a winner is found within the cells.

Comment: What's in those cells? The names?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need two loops:

```
Sub it()
Dim Round1 As Range
Dim Round2 As Range
Dim lngCnt As Long
Dim Winner() As String
Dim pointSum As Double
Dim rng As Range
Dim i As Long
ReDim Winner(1 To 4)
    Winner(1) = "Mohler"
    Winner(2) = "Scotter"
    Winner(3) = "DKGAY"
    Winner(4) = "Lassie"
Set Round1 = Range("L3,L11,L22,L32")
For Each rng In Round1
    For i = 1 To UBound(Winner)
        If rng.Value = Winner(i) Then
            pointSum = pointSum + 10
            Exit For
        End If
    Next i
Next rng

MsgBox pointSum.Value
End Sub
```

The first loops through the ranges the second through the string array.  When it finds where it is equal it adds 10.

Comment: @findwindow Thanks for the catch.  As to fast, it is how my brain is wired.

Comment: Would it be better practice to use `For i = lbound(winner) to ubound(winner)`?  Or is there a time when you'd prefer/want to use `1` instead? (I understand why 1 and not 0, I'm more curious about using a number vs. `LBound()`)

Comment: Since the OP hardcoded the lower bound I was being lazy and used what the OP used. @BruceWayne

Answer (score 1):

A solution with one loop only
I'm not by my PC so can't test nor format it with code tags

```
Sub Main
 Dim Round1 As Range, rng As Range
 Dim Winners As Variant
 Dim pointSum As Double

 Winners =Array ("Mohler","Scotter","DKGAY", "Lassie")
 Set Round1 = Range("L3,L11,L22,L32")
 WinnersStr = "-" & Join (Winners, "-") & "-"
 For Each rng In Round1
     If Instr(WinnersStr, "-" & rng.Value & "-") > 0 Then pointSum = pointSum + 10
Next rng

End Sub
```

Comment: + for getting rid of a loop.